# Help on converting tabularx to longtable

Tags: longtable, tabularx

I have a table written inside a `tabularx` environment, but now is too large and I need to convert it in a longtable, preserving the same column distribution and width. I don't know how to adjust the column width automatically, like does `tabularx`.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\begin{document}

\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{3}{X|p{10pt}|}}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Activo: Sistema de generación de vapor} \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Función} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Falla Funcional\\(Perdida de la funcion)}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Modo de Falla\\(Causa de la falla)}} \\
  \hline
  \parbox[t][0pt]{\hsize}{Evaporar el agua mediante el calor suministrado por el sistema de combustión en horno.} & 1 & \parbox[t][0pt]{\hsize}{No suministra vapor al sistema de distribución} & A & Rotura de tubos fuego  & 1 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Rotura de horno & 2 \\                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                    & & & & Deformación de horno & 3 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Damper atascado  & 4 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Modutrol atascado/quemado  & 5 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Ventilador de tiro atascado/quemado & 6 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Bloqueo total de válvula solenoide de combustible  & 7 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Controlador de llama defectuoso  & 8\\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Foto-celda defectuosa  & 9 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Pressuretrol defectuoso   & 10 \\  
                                                                                                                    & & & & Compresor de aire atascado/quemado   & 11 \\  
                                                                                                                    & & & & Válvulas de purga atascadas en posición \quotes{abierta} & 12 \\


  \cline{3-6}
                                                                                                                    & & \parbox[t][0pt]{\hsize}{Bajo suministro de vapor al sistema de distribución} & B & Bloqueo parcial de válvula solenoide de combustible & 1 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & &Bloqueo parcial de \textit{windbox} & 2 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Fuga de vapor debido a rotura en armazón  & 3 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Válvulas de alivio atascadas en posición \quotes{abierta} & 4 \\

  \hline
 \parbox[t][0pt]{\hsize}{ Contener el agua suministrada por el sistema de alimentación y el vapor de proceso que se genera en su interior. }& 2 & Perdida de contención & A & Rotura de tubos fuego  & 1 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Rotura de horno & 2 \\                     
                                                                                                                    & & & & Rotura de carcasa externa & 3 \\                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                    & & & & Válvulas de alivio atascadas en posición \quotes{abierta} & 4 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Válvulas de purga atascadas en posición \quotes{abierta} & 5 \\

  \hline
\parbox[t][0pt]{\hsize}{Aliviar la presión al interior del sistema en caso de exceder la presión de trabajo llegue a un nivel critico.} & 3 &  \parbox[t][0pt]{\hsize}{Valvulas de alivio no abren a la presión de tarado.} & A & E & F \\
                                                                                                                    & &\parbox[t][0pt]{\hsize}{Apertura prematura a presión inferior a la presión de tarado.}  & B & E & F \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

I dont know if there is some way to adjust the cells to content like `tabularx` and that is my main affair

---

**EDIT**

I tried with the `ltablex` package as suggested by Mr. Kumar (Thank you) but I'm getting this result:

[image]

Comment: `\parbox[t][0pt]` is never going to work with a multi-page table, it specifies that you have large text that fits into zero vertical space overprinting everything below it, so that is always going to hang off the bottom of the page edge and disappear.

Comment: you do not need X columns in this case as you know the width in advance, it does not depend on the table contents, just use `p{..}` where `..` is a third of the textwidth - 10pt - the space for column padding and rules.

Answer (score 3):

With `ltablex` package, you can have `tabularx` that spans multiple pages. Just add `\usepackage{ltablex}` in the preamble. Also remove `[0pt]` from those `\parboxe`s.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\setcellgapes{2pt}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\begin{document}

\makegapedcells
%\keepXColumns
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{3}{X|p{10pt}|}}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Activo: Sistema de generación de vapor} \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Función} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Falla Funcional\\(Perdida de la funcion)}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Modo de Falla\\(Causa de la falla)}} \\
  \hline
  \parbox[t][0pt]{\hsize}{Evaporar el agua mediante el calor suministrado por el sistema de combustión en horno.} & 1 & \parbox[t][0pt]{\hsize}{No suministra vapor al sistema de distribución} & A & Rotura de tubos fuego  & 1 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Rotura de horno & 2 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Deformación de horno & 3 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Damper atascado  & 4 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Modutrol atascado/quemado  & 5 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Ventilador de tiro atascado/quemado & 6 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Bloqueo total de válvula solenoide de combustible  & 7 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Controlador de llama defectuoso  & 8\\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Foto-celda defectuosa  & 9 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Pressuretrol defectuoso   & 10 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Compresor de aire atascado/quemado   & 11 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Válvulas de purga atascadas en posición \quotes{abierta} & 12 \\


  \cline{3-6}
                                                                                                                    & & \parbox[t][0pt]{\hsize}{Bajo suministro de vapor al sistema de distribución} & B & Bloqueo parcial de válvula solenoide de combustible & 1 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & &Bloqueo parcial de \textit{windbox} & 2 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Fuga de vapor debido a rotura en armazón  & 3 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Válvulas de alivio atascadas en posición \quotes{abierta} & 4 \\

  \hline
 \parbox[t]{\hsize}{ Contener el agua suministrada por el sistema de alimentación y el vapor de proceso que se genera en su interior. }& 2 & Perdida de contención & A & Rotura de tubos fuego  & 1 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Rotura de horno & 2 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Rotura de carcasa externa & 3 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Válvulas de alivio atascadas en posición \quotes{abierta} & 4 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Válvulas de purga atascadas en posición \quotes{abierta} & 5 \\

  \hline
\parbox[t]{\hsize}{Aliviar la presión al interior del sistema en caso de exceder la presión de trabajo llegue a un nivel critico.} & 3 &  \parbox[t][0pt]{\hsize}{Valvulas de alivio no abren a la presión de tarado.} & A & E & F \\
                                                                                                                    & &\parbox[t]{\hsize}{Apertura prematura a presión inferior a la presión de tarado.}  & B & E & F \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mr. Kumar. I want to apply the ltablex package just in this table ¿How can I use ltablex with this single table without affecting the entire document?

Comment: @jd1215 Other `tabularx` if not too big, won't split. No need to worry. You can always put them inside `table` environment hence they won't split. Those tabularx which you want to split shall not be inside `table` environment.

Comment: Is not working. Maybe there's a conflict with another package (I have a lot). I'm gonna post a picture with the result. Please check my edit

Answer (score 1):

A  variant with `\tablex`, using its `longtable` functionalities (repeated head on every page). I replaced the \parbox{0pt}`s with an adapted`\multirow`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{array, multirow, makecell}
\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\begin{document}

\makegapedcells\keepXColumns
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{3}{>{\RaggedRight}X|p{10pt}|}}
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\footnotesize (Continued)}\\[1ex]
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Función} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Falla Funcional\\(Perdida de la funcion)}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Modo de Falla\\(Causa de la falla)}} \\
  \hline
\endhead
  \multicolumn{6}{c}{Activo: Sistema de generación de vapor} \\[1ex]
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Función} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Falla Funcional\\(Perdida de la funcion)}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Modo de Falla\\(Causa de la falla)}} \\
  \hline
\endfirsthead
\noalign{\medskip}\multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{\footnotesize To be continued}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
  \multirow{2}{\hsize}{Evaporar el agua mediante el calor suministrado por el sistema de combustión en horno.} & 1 & \parbox[t][0pt]{\hsize}{No suministra vapor al sistema de distribución} & A & Rotura de tubos fuego & 1 \\
    & & & & Rotura de horno & 2 \\
    & & & & Deformación de horno & 3 \\
    & & & & Damper atascado & 4 \\
    & & & & Modutrol atascado/quemado & 5 \\
    & & & & Ventilador de tiro atascado/quemado & 6 \\
    & & & & Bloqueo total de válvula solenoide de combustible & 7 \\
    & & & & Controlador de llama defectuoso & 8\\
    & & & & Foto-celda defectuosa & 9 \\
    & & & & Pressuretrol defectuoso & 10 \\
    & & & & Compresor de aire atascado/quemado & 11 \\
    & & & & Válvulas de purga atascadas en posición \quotes{abierta} & 12 \\
\cline{3-6} & &
\multirow{3}{\hsize} {Bajo suministro de vapor al sistema de distribución} & B & Bloqueo parcial de válvula solenoide de combustible & 1 \\
    & & & &Bloqueo parcial de \textit{windbox} & 2 \\
    & & & & Fuga de vapor debido a rotura en armazón & 3 \\
    & & & & Válvulas de alivio atascadas en posición \quotes{abierta} & 4 \\
  \hline\pagebreak
 \multirow{7}{\hsize}{ Contener el agua suministrada por el sistema de alimentación y el vapor de proceso que se genera en su interior. }
  & 2 & Perdida de contención & A & Rotura de tubos fuego & 1 \\
& & & & Rotura de horno & 2 \\
& & & & Rotura de carcasa externa & 3 \\
& & & & Válvulas de alivio atascadas en posición \quotes{abierta} & 4 \\& & & & Válvulas de purga atascadas en posición \quotes{abierta} & 5 \\
  \hline
\multirow{3}{\hsize}{Aliviar la presión al interior del sistema en caso de exceder la presión de trabajo llegue a un nivel critico.} & 3 & Valvulas de alivio no abren a la presión de tarado. & A & E & F \\
& & Apertura prematura a presión inferior a la presión de tarado. & B & E & F \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]